# MySQLで、条件一致した時だけ値を更新したい場合、「UPDATE SET WHERE」と「UPDATE SET REPLACE」では何が異なるのですか？

Tags: mysql

値が'0'の時だけ''にしたいと思い、「UPDATE SET WHERE」と「UPDATE SET REPLACE」を試したらいずれでも更新できたのですが、両者は何が異なるのですか？　単なるエイリアスですか？　どういう風に使い分けるのですか？

```
UPDATE
  `t`
SET
  `t`.`hoge` =''
WHERE
  `t`.`hoge` = '0'



UPDATE
  `t`
SET
  `t`.`hoge` = REPLACE(`hoge`,0,'');
```

質問背景
SQL構文エラーになった際、書き方が悪いのか、そもそもこんな構文はないのかいつも迷います。

環境
MySQL5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単純にwhere句で処理対象のレコードを絞るかテーブルの全レコードに対して更新処理するかの違いです。

例えば下記のレコードがあった場合…

| id | hoge |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 |

前者のwhere句を使ったSQLでは、最初にwhere句で更新対象を`id`が1,3の行に絞ってから**2レコードのみ**更新処理を行います。

| id | hoge |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 |

後者のwhere句を用いない処理では`id`が1から4まで全レコードに対して更新処理を行います。
例え更新後の結果が更新前と同一であっても、内部的には各レコードすべてが上書きされます。
(つまり`id`2,4はそれぞれ元の値と同じ1,2が代入されます)

実際に[row_count()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/information-functions.html#function_row-count)を使って更新件数を確認すると、後者は全レコードが更新されていることが分かります。
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8cXoGwP5WhtLwbStn5QQMa/0)

通常は両方を使い分けるのではなく前者を使用してください。
後者は[テーブルの完全スキャン](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/glossary.html#glos_full_table_scan)が発生してDB負荷が高いので明確な理由がなければ使う意味がありません。